# Running Android Automotive application on system user (user 0) only

Tags: android, service, aidl, multi-user, android-automotive

I'm building an Android Automotive **system** application that doesn't include any UI.

This service acts as a local backend/proxy on the device waiting for requests from other applications, making the desired action and return the needed data as a response.

Must of the interaction between the service and the other applications are handled using AIDL.

Two questions:

1. Because our system is multiple users aware there are two process created, one for each user - system user (user#0) and a regular user (user#12). Is there any way to notify the system to create only the process for the system user? I tried to mark the receiver as `singleUser=true`, but it didn't help, two process are still created for each user.
2. Another approach that I used was to identify on the boot completed receiver which user is currently running and in case this a regular user disabled the app using `PackageManager.setApplicationEnabledSetting()`, like Google suggested [here](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multiuser-apps#work-profiles). The problem is that when other application is trying to communicate using an AIDL service I'm getting the error below. Worth to mention that each service is marked with `android:exported="true"` and `android:singleUser="true"`. From what I know marking the service as `singleUser=true` should make all the calls to be [routed](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multiuser-apps#enabling_a_singleton_component) to the service running on the system user.
   Am I missing something with the current implementation?

> ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent {
> act=com.companyName.appName.services.serviceName
> pkg=com.companyName.appName } U=12: not found